# How can I see column guides but not all the little grids in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, guides

I am used to seeing what I call 'column guides', the blue nonprinting boxes that suggest the outlines for columns. Now I have done something that gives me either  a view of masses of gridlines and makes my text unreadable OR just a print preview with no guidance at all.

Below is what I see with the grids. Here is what I have tried switching to show/hide guides and frames:

- View>Extras>Show/Hide Frame Edges
- View>Grids & Guides>Show/Hide Guides
- View>Screen Mode>Normal/Preview
- View>Overprint Preview

Comment: Screenshot please

Answer (score 1):

You probably activated Baseline Grid. Just switch it off from the menu.

[image]

Comment: Yep, and also View > Grids & Guides > Hide Document Grid ^^

Answer (score 0):

My team accidentally discovered that if you hold down Ctrl + " (quotation marks key), then a grid appears. I call it a magical grid because it has helped with alignment so much. If you also found that grid by accident, maybe pressing those keys will make it go away. Could you show us a screenshot please of the "little grids"?